# Using the find command with the -cnewer test

Tags: find

I'm trying to understand the output of the find command with the `-cnewer` test. In doing some limited testing, this is what I get.

First, I created a file:

```
cd ~/Documents
touch file1.txt
```

Then I waited a few minutes before creating another file:

```
touch file2.txt
```

Then I decided to compare the content timestamp to the metadata timestamp by doing:

```
ls -lht (for content timestamp)
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mason mason    0 Aug 11 01:19 file2.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mason mason    0 Aug 11 01:17 file1.txt
```

And then:

```
ls -lhtc (for metadata timestamp)
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mason mason    0 Aug 11 01:19 file2.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mason mason    0 Aug 11 01:17 file1.txt
```

So far no surprises, since I haven't done anything to change the metadata timestamp.

Now if I type:

```
chmod 664 file1.txt
```

to change the metadata timestamp, and then look at the output again:

```
ls -lhtc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mason mason    0 Aug 11 01:23 file1.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mason mason    0 Aug 11 01:19 file2.txt
```

`file1.txt` appears in first position in the `ls -lhtc` output, but still in second position in the `ls -lht` output, also as expected.

Finally, if I decide to type:

```
cd ~/Documents
find . -cnewer file1.txt
```

I get:

```
.
./file2.txt
./file1.txt
```

Here are the questions I have:

1. What does `-cnewer` look for? Does it look to see if the metadata timestamp has changed or does it look for whether the *content* timestamp has changed? Does it do both? I'm pretty sure it does both, but I'd like to be sure.
2. If `-cnewer` does both, why does `file1.txt` end up in the output? I can understand why `file2.txt` ends up in the output, since find will look for a more recent content timestamp than `file1.txt`, but I still don't understand why `file1.txt` ends up in the output. After all, there is no file with a more recent metadata timestamp in the `ls -lhtc` output than `file1.txt`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Comparing-Timestamps) (bold mine):

> — Test: `-anewer` *file*
>   — Test: `-cnewer` *file*
>   — Test: `-newer` *file*
>   True if the file was last accessed (or its status changed, or it was
>   modified) more recently than *file* **was modified**. [...]

So the tests compare the atime, ctime and mtime respectively with the **mtime** of the specified file.

If you want to compare ctime with ctime, then use the `-newerXY` tests:

```
find . -newercc file1.txt
```

So, the `-*newer` tests are shorthand for `-newer*m`.

Comment: The info you got from the FSF manual is much more clearer than the man page from the terminal. Thanks.